# Web page content disappears when I select an option from selection list

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I am working on a project for school that uses javascript to dynamically create a selection list, then show content of a web page that is contingent with the option selected in the list. I have a function, characterBox(), that creates the selection list and calls another function, sortLines(). sortLines() is created to show the lines of the character selected in the selection list, and hide the lines of all other characters.

The problem I have is, when I select a character name from the list, all of the content from the 'scene' div disappears. I am new to this and don't know where I went wrong with my code.

I can only use pure JavaScript and cannot refigure the HTML document. Any help debugging my code would be greatly appreciated, as I have been messing around with this for hours and can't fix the problem. Thank you!

Here is a small clip of the HTML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- 
   New Perspectives on HTML, XHTML and DHTML 4th Edition
   Tutorial 16
   Case Problem 4

   The Tempest
   Author: Collin Klopstein
   Date: December 15, 2013  

   Filename:         tempest.htm
   Supporting files: bio_out.jpg, globe_out.jpg, plays.css, plays_out.jpg,
                     scene.js, son_out.jpg, strat_out.jpg
-->

<title>The Tempest, Act V, Scene 1</title>
<link href="plays.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="scene.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="linklist">
   <img src="plays_out.jpg"  alt="The Plays" />
   <img src="son_out.jpg"  alt="The Sonnets" />
   <img src="bio_out.jpg" alt="Biography" />
   <img src="globe_out.jpg" alt="The Globe" />
   <img src="strat_out.jpg" alt="Stratford" />
</div>
<div id="title"><img src="tempest.jpg" alt="The Tempest" /></div>
<div id="actList"><table><tr>
   <td>ACT I</td><td>ACT II</td><td>ACT III</td>
   <td>ACT IV</td><td>ACT V</td>
</tr></table></div>

<div id="characterList"></div>


<div id="sceneIntro">
<h2>Lines from Act V, Scene 1</h2>
</div>

<div id="scene">
<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><i>Enter PROSPERO in his magic robes, and ARIEL</i></blockquote>
<blockquote>Now does my project gather to a head:<br />
My charms crack not; my spirits obey; and time<br />
Goes upright with his carriage. How's the day?
</blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3>
<blockquote>On the sixth hour; at which time, my lord,<br />
You said our work should cease.
</blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote>I did say so,<br />
When first I raised the tempest. Say, my spirit,<br/>
How fares the king and's followers?
</blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3>
<blockquote>Confined together<br />
In the same fashion as you gave in charge,<br />
Just as you left them; all prisoners, sir,<br />
In the line-grove which weather-fends your cell;<br />
They cannot budge till your release. The king,<br />
His brother and yours, abide all three distracted<br />
And the remainder mourning over them,<br />
Brimful of sorrow and dismay; but chiefly<br />
Him that you term'd, sir, 'The good old lord Gonzalo;<br />
His tears run down his beard, like winter's drops<br />
From eaves of reeds. Your charm so strongly works 'em<br />
That if you now beheld them, your affections<br />
Would become tender.
</blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote>Dost thou think so, spirit?
</blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3>
<blockquote>Mine would, sir, were I human.
</blockquote>
```

and the JavaScript file:

```
/*
   New Perspectives on HTML, XHTML, and DHTML 4th Edition
   Tutorial 16
   Case Problem 4

   Author: Collin Klopstein  
   Date: December 15, 2013    

   Filename: scene.js


   Function List:
   uniqueElemText(elemName)
      Returns the unique content from HTML tags with the
      tag name elemName. The list is sorted in alphabetical
      ordered and returned as an array.

*/



function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
   if (object.attachEvent)
       object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
   else if (object.addEventListener)
       object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}

addEvent(window, "load", characterBox, false);//calls createListBox() when page loads
var sourceDoc = document.getElementById("scene");
function uniqueElemText(elemName) {
   elems = document.getElementsByTagName(elemName);
   elemsArray = new Array();

   for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) elemsArray[i]=elems[i].innerHTML;  
   elemsArray.sort();
   for (i=0; i<elemsArray.length-1; i++) {
      if (elemsArray[i]==elemsArray[i+1]) {
         elemsArray.splice(i+1,1);
         i--;
      }
   }
   return elemsArray;
}

function characterBox(object, option) {
    var boxHead = document.getElementById("characterList");//references div with id characterList
    boxHead.innerHTML = "<p>Show Only Lines By:</p>";//adds <p> element to characterList div
    var cList = document.createElement("select");//creates <select> element
    boxHead.appendChild(cList);//appends <select> element to characterList div

    var characters = uniqueElemText("h3");//creates characters array that calls uniqueElemText() and applies all h3 elements

    var showAll = document.createElement("option");//creates option element
    showAll.text = "Show All Character Lines";// value of option element
    showAll.value = 'ALL';
    cList.add(showAll);//adds showAll as option of selection list

    for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        var options = document.createElement("option");
        options.innerHTML = characters[i];
        cList.appendChild(options);
        addEvent(cList, "change", sortLines, false);
    }
}



function sortLines(e) {
    var selection = document.getElementById("characterList");
    var character = this.selection;
    var displayStatus = "";//stores display status to displayStatus var; value empty string, default status applied by browser
    for (var n = document.getElementById("scene").firstChild; n != null; n = n.nextSibling) {
        var nodeName = document.createElement("h3");

        if (nodeName.innerHTML.indexOf("<h3>" + character + "</h3>") != -1) {
            displayStatus = "none";
        }
        else
            displayStatus = "";
    }
    document.getElementById("scene").innerHTML = displayStatus;
}
```

Comment: Your page dissapeared because you put empty content in with the last two lines of `sortLines`. And your variable `character` is undefined. You have to use `character = e.target.value;` Question: you are not allowed to change anything in html file?

Comment: No, I can't change anything in the html file. What do you recommend me doing for the last lines of sortLines(). I'm sorry this is very new to me and I am having a hard time wrapping my head around it. Thank you for taking the time to help me!

Comment: what do I need to set the value of displayStatus to?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to build completely new page on the fly. I you do that than you will not be able to select another character lines or show original page again. What you have to do is to hide neccessary lines and not to delete them from the page.

I'd do the following:

1st option:

- select character
- find all character's headers and its lines
- remove attribyte style with `display:none` from each of those elements
- for all other character headers and their lines:

  - add attribyte style with `display:none` to each of those elements

The result should be something like:

```
<h3 style='display:none;'>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote style='display:none;'><i>Enter PROSPERO in his magic robes, and ARIEL</i></blockquote>
<blockquote style='display:none;'>Now does my project gather to a head:<br />
My charms crack not; my spirits obey; and time<br />
Goes upright with his carriage. How's the day?
</blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3>
...
```

2nd option:

- add styling to head section with class hide with rule `display:none` or add the same rule to `play.css` if it is possible
- select character
- find all character's headers and its lines
- remove class named `hide` from each of those elements
- for all other character headers and their lines:

  - add class hide to each of those elements

The result should be something like:

```
<h3 class='hide'>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote class='hide'><i>Enter PROSPERO in his magic robes, and ARIEL</i></blockquote>
<blockquote class='hide'>Now does my project gather to a head:<br />
My charms crack not; my spirits obey; and time<br />
Goes upright with his carriage. How's the day?
</blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3>
...
```

and new css rule:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

And I'd change the name of `sortLines()` function to `showLines()`.